# Перебор строки и конвертация в int

Tags: c++

```
string str = "4fd8bfb78d5291eb809d0beab33acf4ae505e1df";
const char * cstr = str.c_str();
stringstream std;
int summ = 0; 
for(unsigned int i=0; strlen(cstr) > i; i++)
{
    std << cstr[i]; 
    summ += atoi(std.str().c_str());
    std.str("");
}
```

Смысл кода думаю ясен, интересует как можно реализовать более адекватно...

Comment: Если цикл руками писать не хочется, то 

``std::accumulate( str.c_str(), str.c_str() + str.size(), 0, [](size_t sz, char c){ return sz + (c - '0'); } );``

функцияю, понятно, нужно подпилить так, чтобы буквы корректно обрабатывались

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Если я правильно понял ваш код, то ваша задача - посчитать сумму цифр в строке. Делается это значительно проще:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < strlen(cstr); i++) {
    if (cstr[i] >= '0' && cstr[i] <= '9') {
        summ += cstr[i] - '0';
    }
}
```

Читайте про ASCII и коды символов. Если же ваша задача была посчитать сумму всех *чисел* в строке, то код немного усложнится, но принцип останется похожим.

Comment: Больше спасибо.

Comment: А чтобы не вызывать strlen на каждой итерации, можно подпилить так: вместо условия i < strlen(cstr) в цикле записать cstr[i].

Comment: @paulgri: ну или хотя бы закешировать значение `strlen`.